# Installing and switching to desktop environment on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: command-line, server

I am fairly new to Ubuntu Server. I know it is possible to install a desktop environment. Once I have done so, how can I:

1. Always boot into the command-line?
2. Start the desktop environment from the command-line?
3. Switch back to the command-line from the desktop environment?

My goal is to be able to VNC into the desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not recommended, Install your desired desktop first.

Then:

1. `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
2. `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`
3. `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target`

Answer (score 0):

1. I think even after installing desktop environment you will boot into the command line. In order to run DE at startup you will have to enable proper startup services using `systemctl enable [put service name here]`.
2. You have to look up the command for starting the desired desktop. For xfce, the command is `startxfce4`.
3. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer for that. :(